# SVG zoom on mouse wheel using svgcanvas in chrome

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, svg

I am trying to zoom a svg on mouse wheel. In IE it works fine but in chrome does not respond to it. My svg looks like.. sample.. its not the exact one.

```
<svg width="1188" height="840" zoomAndPan="magnify" style="fill:none;stroke:black; font-size:4.07314px;stroke-width:0.509143"  viewBox="0 0 1188 840">

<g id="XMP_1" style="stroke:#000000; stroke-width:0.339429">
  <path d="M554 401L641 401" style="stroke:#0000FF; stroke-dasharray: 3.5640  3.5640  3.5640  3.5640"/>
</g>

</svg>
```

And my zoom function is as below:

```
var zoomToUserPoint = function (userPoint, zoomFactor) {
            // This will usually cause a resize event, so we need to flag that it was caused by
            // internal interaction with the SVG document.
            currentView.internalResize = true;

            // changing the scale will raise a zoom event (immediately) 
            // which will affect where the centre of the screen will be in user coordinates
            if (zoomFactor !== 1) {
                var newscale = applyScalingLimits(svgroot.currentScale * zoomFactor);

                // THIS currentScale NEVER CHANGES IN CHROME

                if (newscale !== svgroot.currentScale) {
                    svgroot.currentScale = newscale;
                }
            }

            var currentScale = canvas.getScale();

            // get the centre of the screen in user coordinates
            var screenCentre = svgUtilities.screenCoordinateTransform(canvas.getScreenCentre(), svgroot);

            // compute necessary change to current translation to centre screen point
            svgroot.currentTranslate.x = svgroot.currentTranslate.x + (screenCentre.x - userPoint.x) / currentScale.x;
            svgroot.currentTranslate.y = svgroot.currentTranslate.y + (screenCentre.y - userPoint.y) / currentScale.y;

            // Cache the current view centre
            //currentView.viewCentre = svgUtilities.screenCoordinateTransform(canvas.getScreenCentre(), svgroot);

            // need to resize selector grips etc for any selected mark-up
            canvas.resizeSelectors();

            // Flag that we have finished with any interaction that may have caused a resize event
            currentView.internalResize = false;
        };
```

I tried to figure out the problem and found svg currentScale property doesn't change on google chrome.

How to fix this??
I'm frustrated now.. no fix at all... :(

Comment: What does applyScalingLimits do?

Comment: It restricts the maximum zoom. The problem is with only chrome where svgroot.currentScale never get changed and every time its 1 whereas other browsers such as IE assigns the newscale to current scale.

Answer (score 0):

This has been a bug in Chrome for some time now.

Here's the link to a registered bug http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=174568
but this has been registered as a bug before and ignored

The bug entry contains a link to the SVG spec for currentScale and a link to a Plunker that demonstrates the problem

Comment: Yes i'm aware of that. Is there any workaround to it? i tried setting the webkit scale on css. But i could not make it work on mouse wheel.

Comment: This doesn't really answer the question - you've explained the cause, but the question is asking for a solution. Do you know of any way to achieve what @Joe is after?

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.